# Random TMZ on a dateTime [Spreadsheet]

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a starting time in "HH:MM:SS" format. In my spreadsheet, the user enters it in this format, like "09:00:00" for 9AM. When I get this cell's value in my script, I get this weirdo :

"Sat Dec 30 09:00:00 GMT+00:09 1899"

It seems like I have that random date of Sat Dec 30 1899, which I don't really care about, but also the "GMT+00:09", that bothers me a lot more. My spreadsheet and script are "GMT+01:00 Paris", so when I insert this data elsewhere, I get 09:50 GMT+01:00... Not even 51 minutes off, as I would have expected.

Do you have any idea how and why it happens ?

The fix I use right now is to display the time in my "HH:MM:SS" format, or "HH:MM", but set the value to, say "05/01/2018 09:00:00", so it is considered a full dateTime in my timezone. I would really like to be able to only specify the time here.

Thanks for your answers,

Comment: One fast fix-solution is to set the number formatting in the cells to plain text. For some reason one of my spreadsheets always added 20min to the time when the format was 'time' or 'date'. Could not even reproduce the issue on other spreadsheets. And I cannot even make up a timezone that is 20min off to mine.

Comment: That seems to be the same kind of problem, a 9-minutes offset is nowhere to be found about of course ! Plain text is just another quick fix, I found the most fitting fix for now, but it's not really what I am looking for here... Thanks for your input anyways =)

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer? This answer supposes the following condition.

- Format of cell "A1" is `HH:MM:SS` for time.
- Value of cell "A1" is `09:00:00`.

#### In your 1st case :

When the value of "A1" is retrieved by `getValue()`, the value is `Sat Dec 30 09:00:00 GMT+09:00 1899`. (I'm sorry. "GMT+09:00" is due to the time zone. My time zone is Asia/Tokyo.) Because Spreadsheet uses Serial Number for Date/Time. The start of serial number is `12/30/1899 00:00:00`. In this case, because there are no date information, `Sat Dec 30 09:00:00 GMT+09:00 1899` is retrieved as the value which elapsed for `09:00:00` from the start.

If you want to retrieve `09:00:00` from cell "A1", please use `getDisplayValue()` instead of `getValue()`. By this, you can retrieve `09:00:00`.

#### In your 2nd case :

I think that this is better usage. `05/01/2018 09:00:00` is imported to the cell with the format of `HH:MM:SS`. By this, the value has the information of both date and time. So the values of cell retrieved by `getValue()` and `getDisplayValue()` are `Fri Jan 05 09:00:00 GMT+09:00 2018` and `09:00:00`, respectively.

#### Sample :

In the case using `getValue()`

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
```

In the case using `getDisplayValue()`

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
```

#### References :

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)
- [Date/Time serial numbers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#datetime_serial_numbers)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Well, getDisplayValue() could work in this case, but might add problems elsewhere. And it does not explain where that 9-minute offset is coming from... As I said, I already have a kind of quick fix that works well but is not fully satisfying. Thanks for your input anyways =)

Comment: @Tanaike, the 1899 year part is clear. The strange things happen in `GMT+00:09` part. This is very curious, I had `+01:44`, and can't explain this. Please, post if you know about this case, is it some issue?

Comment: @Josselin PEREZ I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I misunderstood your question. I'm really sorry.

Comment: I don't know whether this is a correct answer. So please think of this as one of several answers. I had thought that the offset is due to each time zone. Specifically, it's due to the zoneinfo database (it's called tz database) created by [zic](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zic). I thought that from this database, the offset was created.